# Unexpected options when attempting to publish mobile service to Azure using VS2015

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am following a series of instructions to deploy a mobile backend using Azure Mobile Services.
As part of that workflow I get to download a personalized backend app which downloads as Visual studio solution.
It builds fine and the next step is to publish it to Azure.

Instead of seeing the choice below (**Microsoft Azure App Service**) I am seeing 2 different choices

- **Microsoft Azure Web Apps**, or
- **Microsoft Azure API Apps** **(Preview).**

[image: Publishing a Mobile Service .net backend to Azure]

So, I chose the closest option (Web Apps) provided and it logs me into Azure and in a box which reports existing web apps I see none.
Yet I've deployed a mobile app in the Azure portal earlier.

In some of what I've been reading online it mentions a Publisher profile. I am just a bit stumped by not getting the "Microsoft Azure App Service" choice when I go to publish my backend to the cloud.

Here is the tutorial/guide which I am following (January 2016).
Perhaps the VS/Azure integration has changed since then or maybe I've more configuration steps missing.
[Azure .NET mobile backend using Azure Mobile Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/)
Any guidance would be hugely welcome.
At this stage I am stuck as far as what I need to do to get my mobile backend published to Azure.

Answer (score 1):

You have got an older version of the Azure SDK installed.  The latest version of the Azure SDK provides the Azure App Service publish dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've solved this for now.
I was able to download a publish profile from the Azure Console which I could import within the "publish" dialog in VS2015.
I now have the mobile app up and running in Azure.